# Dúvida utilizando array

Tags: java, array, array-multidimensional

Gostaria de saber o motivo de no código ser utilizado o índice `0` quando é feito um `for` para identificar se o tamanho do array é menor do que o contador `j`.

```
public class Aplicacao {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int[][] array = new int[3][5];

        array[1][4] = 20;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) { // <-- aqui, por que array[0]?
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + "  ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Vamos por partes:

```
int[][] array
```

Aqui é declarado um array de arrays de `int`. É um array no qual cada elemento é outro array, que por sua vez contém números inteiros.

```
int[][] array = new int[3][5];
```

Aqui eu indico que este array possui 3 posições, e que cada uma destas posições contém um outro array com 5 posições.

> Vale lembrar duas coisas:
>
> - as posições de um array começam em zero (ou seja, `array[0]` é o primeiro elemento, `array[1]` é o segundo, etc).
> - todos os elementos são inicializados com um valor *default*. No caso de `int`, [o valor é zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3426854)

Ou seja, foi criado um array com 3 posições. Cada uma destas posições é outro array com 5 valores `int`, que por sua vez foram inicializados com o valor `0` (zero).

---

Para percorrer o array, foi usado um `for` tradicional:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
```

No primeiro `for` eu percorro os 3 elementos de `array`, usando `array.length` como critério de parada (assim eu garanto que o `for` não vai avançar além do tamanho do array).

Como cada um dos elementos de `array` é outro array, eu faço o segundo `for` para percorrê-lo. Mas como todos os arrays de `int` têm o mesmo tamanho (que no caso é 5), foi usado o tamanho do primeiro (`array[0].length`) como critério de parada. Mesmo se eu estiver no segundo ou no terceiro array, o tamanho deles é igual ao do primeiro (sempre é 5), e por isso o `for` não avança além do tamanho de cada array.

---

Por que fizeram assim? Sei lá, talvez porque tenha "funcionado", ou porque pensaram "o tamanho de todos é o mesmo, tanto faz qual usar". O problema é que esse código confia cegamente no fato de que todos os arrays têm o mesmo tamanho, o que nem sempre será verdade:

```
// criar array com 3 posições, cada posição é outro array, mas ainda não defini os tamanhos
int[][] array = new int[3][];
array[0] = new int[20]; // primeiro array tem 20 elementos
array[1] = new int[3]; // segundo array tem 3 elementos
array[2] = new int[10]; // terceiro array tem 10 elementos
```

Agora cada array tem um tamanho diferente. Se eu usar sempre o tamanho do primeiro (que é 20), dará um erro de `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ao tentar acessar o quarto elemento do segundo array (já que ele só tem 3 elementos, mas o segundo `for` tentará acessar o quarto elemento, pois ele está indo até `array[0].length`, que é 20).

Neste caso, o ideal é usar o tamanho do array que você está percorrendo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                              ^ usar i em vez de 0
```

Só porque o primeiro código "funcionou" usando `array[0]`, não quer dizer que seja o mais correto a se fazer.

Comment: "Por que fizeram assim? Sei lá" Só sei que eu ri quando li essa parte da resposta

Answer (score 1):

Olá.

```
// inicializacao da matriz
int[][] array = new int[3][5];

// inicializar a segunda linha, terceira coluna com o valor int 20
array[1][4] = 20;
```

Para todo o caso, `array[0]` identifica a primeira linha na matriz, sendo que na incialização foi usado o 3 como valor, a matriz tem agora 3 linhas, sendo elas:

```
array[0]
array[1]
array[2]
```

Agora, os tamanhos ou o numero de colunas para essas 3 linhas são os mesmos, por isso usar `array[n-1].length` (`array[0].length`, `array[1].length`, `array[2].length`) dá no mesmo.

```
System.out.println(array.length);
// saida: 3
System.out.println(array[0].length);
// saida: 5
```